# Detect owl carousel drag direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag, direction, owl-carousel

I need your help. I need to detect owl carousel dragging direction.

```
function startCallback(event) {
    // if drag left do this
    $(".owl-item").css("transform", "rotate(-10deg)");
    //if drag left do this
    $(".owl-item").css("transform", "rotate(10deg)");
}

function endCallback(event) {

}
```

I need detect drag direction when it start.
Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Add more code, for example the code of carousel...

Comment: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/ you can use plugin demo

Comment: There are callbacks predefined, like onDrag, onDragged, onTranslate and so on, but the docs is not enought. I guess that in these callbacks you will receive some attributes to find out the direction

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions.  This doesn't have anything to do with [tag:owl], the Web Ontology Language.  I've retagged appropriately.